# how to test if xi is significantly greater than yi

Tags: statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics

I have two observations for each row of my dataset:

My Dataset looks like this:

```
 Company1 |  2016 |    x1 | y1 
 Company1 |  2017 |    x2 | y2 
 Company2 |  2016 |    x3 | y3 
 Company2 |  2017 |    x4 | y4 
 ...
```

I want to prove with a statistical test, that the $X$ values are significantly larger than the $Y$ values. Meaning, that the difference $X$ - $Y$ is tendencially positive.

Answer (score 2):

If you assume each row is independent to each other, you could just calculate the difference of X - Y, and perform the paired sample t-test on these differences to see if they are greater than zero or not.
However, it looks like you repeated measure each company twice (2016 & 2017) so it violates the independent assumption of t test. You may need to use the repeated measure ANOVA instead.
This link might be helpful: https://statistics.laerd.com/statistical-guides/repeated-measures-anova-statistical-guide.php

Answer (score 1):

The RV $X$ being larger than the RV $Y$ is referred to as $X$ being *[stochastically greater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_ordering)* than $Y$. The [Mann-Whitney U Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test#Assumptions_and_formal_statement_of_hypotheses) tests this very hypothesis.

Comment: The form of the data suggests you ought to control for year.